# Why doesn't type inference work here?

Tags: scala, structural-typing, type-bounds

This problem arose in a module I'm writing, but I have made a minimal case that exhibits the same behaviour.

```
class Minimal[T](x : T) {
  def doSomething = x
}

object Sugar {
  type S[T] = { def doSomething : T }
  def apply[T, X <: S[T]] (x: X) = x.doSomething
}

object Error {
  val a = new Minimal(4)
  Sugar(a) // error: inferred [Nothing, Minimal[Int]] does not fit the bounds of apply
  Sugar[Int, Minimal[Int]](a) // works as expected
}
```

The problem is that the compiler manages to figure out the inner parameter for `Minimal` (`Int`), but then sets the other occurrence of `T` to `Nothing`, which obviously does not match `apply`. These are definitely the same `T`, as removing the first parameter makes the second complain that T is not defined.

Is there some ambiguity that means that the compiler cannot infer the first parameter, or is this a bug? Can I work around this gracefully?

Further information: This code is a simple example of an attempt at syntactic sugar. The original code tries to make `|(a)|` mean the modulus of `a`, where a is a vector. Clearly `|(a)|` is better than writing `|[Float,Vector3[Float]](a)|`, but unfortunately I can't use `unary_|` to make this easier.

The actual error:

> inferred type arguments [Nothing,Minimal[Int]] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [T,X <: Sugar.S[T]]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a Scala compiler bug, but it's certainly a limitation of Scala's type inference. The compiler wants to determine the bound on `X`, `S[T]`, before solving for `X`, but the bound mentions the so far unconstrained type variable `T` which it therefore fixes at `Nothing` and proceeds from there. It doesn't revisit `T` once `X` has been fully resolved ... currently type inference always proceeds from left to right in this sort of case.

If your example accurately represents your real situation then there is a simple fix,

```
def apply[T](x : S[T]) = x.doSomething
```

Here `T` will be inferred such that `Minimal` conforms to `S[T]` directly rather than via an intermediary bounded type variable.

**Update**

Joshua's solution also avoids the problem of inferring type `T`, but in a completely different way.

```
def apply[T, X <% S[T]](x : X) = x.doSomething
```

desugars to,

```
def apply[T, X](x : X)(implicit conv : X => S[T]) = x.doSomething
```

The type variables `T` and `X` can now be solved for independently (because `T` is no longer mentioned in `X`'s bound). This means that `X` is inferred as `Minimal` immediately, and `T` is solved for as a part of the implicit search for a value of type `X => S[T]` to satisfy the implicit argument `conv`. `conforms` in `scala.Predef` manufactures values of this form, and in context will guarantee that given an argument of type `Minimal`, `T` will be inferred as Int. You could view this as an instance of [functional dependencies](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/) at work in Scala.

Comment: Yes, this solution works fine in my case. It is also cleaner than Joshua's solution (sorry Joshua!). Can you explain why Joshua's solution works, then?

Comment: Answer updated to give an explanation of why Joshua's solution also works.

Answer (score 4):

There's some weirdness with bounds on structural types, try using a view bound on S[T] instead.

`def apply[T, X <% S[T]] (x: X) = x.doSomething` works fine.

Comment: Great, this works, but surely there should be no difference between the approaches? Taking a view in this case is just casting to a superclass, isn't it? Does this mean that this fix is just a workaround for a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Ah, now I see, `S` is not a superclass - it is just a view (in a sense). So a view bound is more appropriate, despite not being required in most cases.