# Scala: Why doesn't this compile?

Tags: scala, generics

Given:

```
class Foo[T] {
 def get: T
}

class Bar
class FooBar extends Foo[Bar] {
 def get = new Bar
}

object Baz {
    def something [T, U <: Foo[T]] (foo : Class[U]): T = foo.newInstance.get
}
```

I should be able to do something like this, right?

```
Baz.something(classOf[FooBar])
```

Strangely this is throwing:

```
inferred type arguments [Nothing,this.FooBar] do not conform to method something's type parameter bounds [T,U <: this.Foo[T]]
```

Which is weird :S. BTW I'm having this issue while migrating some java code that's equivalent to what I write here and it's working fine.

Comment: `Foo` class is missing an `abstract` keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run into one of the more annoying limitations of Scala's type inference! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347307) for a clear explanation of why the compiler is choking here.

You have a handful of options. Most simply you can just provide the types yourself:

```
Baz.something[Bar, FooBar](classOf[FooBar])
```

But that's annoyingly verbose. If you really don't care about `U`, you can leave it out of the type argument list:

```
object Baz {
  def something[T](foo: Class[_ <: Foo[T]]): T = foo.newInstance.get
}
```

Now `FooBar` will be inferred correctly in your example. You can also use a trick discussed in the answer linked above:

```
object Baz {
  def something[T, U <% Foo[T]](foo: Class[U]): T = foo.newInstance.get
}
```

*Why* this works is a little tricky—the key is that after the view bound is desugared, `T` no longer appears in `U`'s bound.

Answer (score 5):

It does not compile because `T` does not appear anywhere in the parameter list and thus cannot be inferred(or rather, it is inferred to `Nothing`).

You can fix it like this:

```
def something [T] (foo : Class[_ <: Foo[T]]): T = foo.newInstance.get
```

Comment: Very true! Missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the types explicitly seems to work:

```
scala> Baz.something[Bar,FooBar](classOf[FooBar])
res1: Bar = Bar@3bb0ff0
```

Usually, when you get a `Nothing` where you expect some other type to be inferred means that for some reason the compiler is not able to infer the type in that particular position.

That said, I propose the question: how could we refactor the code so the type gets inferred? @Régis' answer shows the solution.