# Scala: bug in implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

The following is a simplified version of my real problem:

```
class Z[T]
object E extends Enumeration {
  implicit val z = new Z[Value] 
  val X, Y = Value
}
implicit def f[T : Z] = (getter: T) => 0
implicit def o[T](v: Option[T])(implicit toInt: T => Int) = 0
def e: Option[E.Value] = null
val b: Int = e
```

This works, with b implicitly converted to o(e)(f(E.z)). But with the small changes following:

```
implicit def f[T : Z] = (setter: T => Unit) => 0
implicit def o[T](v: Option[T])(implicit toInt: (T => Unit) => Int) = 0
```

it fails finding the appropriate implicit value E.z although there's no essential difference from the original code, while manual explicit conversion to o(e)(f(E.z)) still works.

I know the implementation of implicit parameter is not complete yet and there are still many unresolved issues. If this is one of them, I'd like to report it to the Scala contributors. So my question is, a) is this really a bug? b) if so, where and how can I file a bug so that it could be fixed in the future?

**UPDATE**

Travis' answer worked like a charm! By the way, the code above was a workaround to my original problem:

```
implicit object E extends Enumeration { val X, Y = Value }
implicit object F extends Enumeration { val X, Y = Value }
implicit def f[T <: Enumeration](getter: T#Value)(implicit e: T) = 0
implicit def o[T](v: Option[T])(implicit toInt: T => Int) = 0
val b: Int = Some[E.Value](null)
```

In this code, the situation was the other way around: it works with the setter version but not with the simpler getter version. The compiler complains that it's confusing whether to use E or F as the implicit parameter though using F doesn't actually compile nor make sense. I managed to get it working by doing a similar thing:

```
implicit def f[S <% T => T, T <: Enumeration](getter: T#Value)(implicit e: T) = 0
```

This works, and although I somehow could get it working, I still don't understand the logic behind this magic.

Comment: Interesting. Running this with `-Xlog-implicits`, it seems that `T` in `f[T : Z]` is not inferred as `E.Value`. Hence this works: `val b: Int = o(e)(f[E.Value])` but this doesn't: `val b: Int = o(e)(f)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run into a yet another variation of [this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961911/334519) of Scala's type inference system.

The compiler will resolve the `T` for `f` if in the first case, where it's looking for an implicit conversion from plain old `E.Value` to `Int`, but not in the second, where it wants a conversion from `E.Value => Unit` (i.e., `Function1[E.Value, Unit]`) to `Int`.

Fortunately there's an easy workaround in cases like this—just use a view bound:

```
implicit def f[F <% T => Unit, T: Z] = (setter: F) => 0
```

This will desugar to something like the following:

```
implicit def f[F, T](implicit st: F <:< (T => Unit), ev: Z[T]) = (setter: F) => 0
```

Now when the compiler wants a conversion from `E.Value => Unit` to `Int` it'll be able to resolve `F` to `E.Value => Unit` immediately and then  `T` to `E.Value`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked like a charm! But I still don't understand how this magic works.. Can you take a look at the update above and give an explanation? Looks like S doesn't even need to make sense to get the type inference system working.. Mysterious.